# Shall tags xml-dsig and xmldsig become synonyms?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request, retag-request

They are not listed on on https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135994/172431. I can't see any difference between them, so maybe we could make [xmldsig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xmldsig) a synonym for [xml-dsig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xml-dsig). Or should both become synonyms of [xml-signature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xml-signature)? I can see no differences in meaning.

Comment: @Downvoter: What do you think is wrong with this question?

Comment: Possibly the downvoter thinks that they shouldn't be synonyms.

Comment: But then the he should leave an explanation why they are not synonymous. As far as I have seen, all of them refer to to same thing.

Answer (score 3):

I retagged and generally cleaned up all the [xmldsig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xmldsig) questions, so this is done.

[image: Trogdor]